# Is it correct to say "get to sleep" in this situation?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Now it is 10 pm and you put your daughter on the bed and tuck her in and you want her to fall asleep quickly.

Now your daughter sit up and talk and play with toys on the bed.

I see this in Oxford dictionary

> [intransitive] **[get to do something](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get?q=get)** to reach the point at which you
> feel, know, are, etc. something
>
> After a time you get to realize that these things don't matter.
>
> You'll like her once you get to know her.

Can I say to my daughter "**quickly get to sleep**" or "**quickly fall asleep**" or "**go to sleep**" in this situation?

I don 't think "**go to bed**" is suitable because she is already in bed.

Comment: To ***get to do something*** means to ***achieve the chance/capability** of doing it.* To ***get someone to do something*** means to ***persuade / force** them to do it*.

Comment: To use an imperative is like giving a direct order or command. These are often used in English to express annoyance/impatience with the situation. Is that what you intend here? If not, then you might want to tone it down a bit - something less direct like "It's time to get/go to sleep now"

Comment: **I finally got to sleep** means "I managed to fall asleep, but later than I had intended" (because you weren't sleepy or because some kind of noise was keeping you awake). If you want someone else to compose themself for sleep you would tell them to **go to sleep**.

Comment: You could say "settle down" to her.

Comment: You can tell an older child you no longer tuck in, "Get to bed! It's a school night." It means, "stop horsing around and go to bed, there's school tomorrow" or "enough TV|video games|whatever, go to bed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that if she’s already in bed, then *Go to bed* would not be appropriate. And *Get to sleep*, with or without *quickly*, would be somewhat odd since falling asleep is at least partially beyond one’s intentional control. The idiomatic way to express your meaning would be to say to her, “Go to sleep.”

To my ear, the difference between *get* and *go* is this: One **gets** to sleep exactly at the moment at which one passes out of wakefulness and into sleep. That’s why instructing someone to *get to sleep* can sound a bit strange—something like, “Are you ready? Here we go… three, two, one, be asleep!” By contrast, one’s **going** to sleep is not instantaneous, but a process, a phase of gradual transition, sometimes lengthy and sometimes brief. So the instruction to go to sleep amounts to telling someone to engage in that process, to undertake the gradual transition. And that instruction seems more reasonable (because under the other person’s control).

I’d add, perhaps confusing matters, that *Get to bed* is entirely idiomatic, though not applicable in your scenario. Being on or in bed is a state that can be reached essentially in an instant, and entirely at will.

Comment: There is a song saying "Now close your eyes and go to sleep.
Goodnight. Sleep tight. Sweet dreams tonight"